# Xamarin UI Testing on Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, xamarin, testing, automated-tests

I've been trying for hours trying to get the Xamarin UI Testing project type to show up by installing various visual studio packages, as well as attempting to add the Xamarin.UITesting nuget package to my existing unit testing project. I've consulted dozens of guides on the subject and read bug reports and stack overflow questions.

I can't find it definitively stated anywhere, but I think I've finally decided that I need the enterprise version of Visual Studio. Can anyone just confirm that for me?

Comment: Can you describe the issue you encountered? What did you do? You could show some related codes.

Comment: There is no code to relay because I'm just trying to get the template to even show up as an option. I found that on a separate computer we have with the same version that the template was an option, so I created it there, transferred it over and so far I seem to be able to use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that on a separate computer we have with the same version that the template was an option, so I created it there, transferred it over and so far I seem to be able to use it. Still not sure why it won't show up on my primary development computer.

Comment: Hi, I've the same problem. Could you share an empty project on Github or somewhere?